# Ranking results based on relevancy in mysql

Tags: mysql, sorting

My table looks like this

```
id, name
 1, ccc hij
 2, bbb
 3, hsd
```

Now if I query for `SELECT id, name FROM tbl WHERE name LIKE 'h%' OR '% h%';`

it gives me this as the output

```
id, name
1, ccc hij
3, hsd
```

Which is correct, but not in proper order. I can't even `ORDER BY name` since `ccc hij` would anyways get to top in natural sorting.

What option do I have to show item starting from user's keyword in the top and wildcard matches in the bottom?

**Update:**

Consider following input

```
1   ccc hij
2   hsd
3   hdb
4   haa
```

and the `order by (name LIKE 'h%') DESC` as suggested. I get following output

```
2   hsd
3   hdb
4   haa
1   ccc hij
```

Is is possible to sort `'h%'` matches alphabetically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL has a neat feature where boolean are converted to ones and zeroes when treated as numbers. So one way to handle this requirement is to order according to whether the column matches a wildcard or not:

```
SELECT   id, name 
FROM     tbl 
WHERE    name LIKE 'h%' OR name LIKE '% h%'
ORDER BY (name LIKE 'h%') DESC
```

Comment: O great, adding an extra clause **`, bank_name`** after the `order by` solves this. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

First, look at a text engine that will return you a relevancy number.  MYSQL [has one](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-natural-language.html), or you can go out to solr/elasticsearch/cloudsearch/etc.

Second, queries with wildcards at the front can't use an index, so "% h%" will cause a sequential scan of the table.

Finally, you can do what you want with a CASE statement:

```
SELECT id, name,
  CASE
    WHEN name like 'h%' then 100
    WHEN name like '% h%' then 5
  END as score
FROM tbl
WHERE name LIKE 'h%' OR '% h%'
ORDER BY score DESC
```

The nice thing about this is that you can have multiple, complex score conditions (each WHEN clause).

Comment: Nice. Great thing I learnt. And +1 for provision of multiple complex conditions for sorting. Though in my case, this particular table will have maximum ~1k rows, so I think I should go with the simpler solution. Thanks.